# Swift code conversion: nsevent

Tags: swift2

I have the following code

```
class cl : NSView {    

override func keyDown (theEvent:NSEvent) {
       if theEvent.modifierFlags & NSEventModifierFlags.ShiftKeyMask == nil {
       ...
```

with the latest update this generates the error 
Binary operator cannot be applied to two NSEventModifierFlags.

I cannot find how to fix this, all help is welcome.

Comment: which xcode and swift version are you using?

Comment: Xcode 7.0, swift 2.0

Comment: are you using import AppKit ? or Cocca?

Comment: I'm using import Cocoa

Comment: I am trying to reproduce your problem, but i wasn't able to instanciate the NSEvent, even with the import of Cocca

Comment: Thx for you assistance!! I've expand the problematic code with some context.

Comment: Doesn't NSEventModifierFlags conform to OptionSetType? Try writing it this way: `if event.modifierFlags.contains(.ShiftKeyMask)...`

Comment: Thanks alot. That did it